# Multiple lines multiple string to one line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

Input (multiple lines):

```
abc def ghi 123 345 456 
abc def def ghi 123 345 456
abc def def def ghi 123 345 456
```

Output (extract string/regex from one line to one line):

```
def 345
def def 345
def def def 345
```

First..

```
echo "abc 123" | grep -Po "\Kabc|\K123"
```

but this prints two lines:

```
abc
123
```

Second:

```
echo -ne "abc def bac 123\nabc def def bac 123\nabc def def def bac 123 123\n" | grep -Po "def|123" | paste -d ' ' - -
```

But this shows:

```
def 123
def def
123 def
def def
123 123
```

I want:

```
def 123
def def 123
def def def 123 123
```

I can't use tr to remove \n, def or 345 can be found multiple times in one line, then removing every second line \n have no sense. I can't use a column separator.

Comment: What decides what should be extracted from each line?

Comment: Using regex or specified word. I added some more scription in post,

Comment: The `grep` man page says: "...  Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with `each such part on a separate output line`" (emphasis added); in other words, you cannot use `grep -o`:  you lose the information about line boundaries, and there is no way to reconstruct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `perl`

```
$ cat ip.txt
abc def ghi 123 345 456 
abc def def ghi 123 345 456
abc def def def ghi 123 345 456 1234

$ perl -lane 'print join " ", grep { /def|123/ } @F' ip.txt
def 123
def def 123
def def def 123 1234

$ perl -lane 'print join " ", grep { $_ eq "def" || $_ eq "123" } @F' ip.txt
def 123
def def 123
def def def 123
```

- `-lane` here `-l` will strip newline from input line and add it back when `print` is used, `-a` will autosplit input line on whitespaces and save results in `@F` array, `-n` will loop over input lines but won't automatically print the lines after processing and `-e` enables to provide Perl script from command line
- `grep { /def|123/ } @F` will filter all elements of `@F` array if they contain `def` or `123`

  - if you want string match instead of regex, you can use `grep { $_ eq "def" || $_ eq "123" } @F`
- `print join " "` print the elements obtained from `grep` output with space as delimiter

Answer (score 1):

Using `ex` with `awk`:

```
$ cat test.txt
abc def ghi 123 345 456 
abc def def ghi 123 345 456
abc def def def ghi 123 345 456
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/^/.!awk -v ORS=" " -v RS=" " "/^(def|345)$/"' %p | ex test.txt
def 345 
def def 345 
def def def 345 
$
```

What this does is:

1. Reads the file into a buffer (in `ex`) where it can be modified, printed, and/or saved;
2. Filters each individual line of the buffer through an `awk` script (separately);
3. Prints the entire contents of the buffer (with `%p`).

The above command does not save the results back into the file.  If you want to do that, just replace the `%p` with `x`.

---

Longer explanation:

`ex` is the scriptable file editor.  It accepts the name of a file (`test.txt`) as the argument, and takes editing commands from its standard input.

Here we provide the editing commands using `printf`.  The first argument to `printf` is the formatting string, in this case `'%s\n'`, which is used to control how the rest of the arguments to `printf` are output.  We're saying that all the arguments will be strings, and a newline character should be printed after each.  (The single quotes are to avoid having the shell interpret the backslash—we want `printf` to get the backslash, not the shell.)

There are two arguments we're sending to `ex` using `printf`.  Here they are:

```
g/^/.!awk -v ORS=" " -v RS=" " "/^(def|345)$/"
%p
```

The second of these is easiest.  `%` is an address range; it means "the entire buffer."  `p` is the print command.  So that just means "print the entire buffer."

The first one takes some breaking down.

`g/.../` is the "global" command.  It searches the whole buffer for lines which match the given pattern (in this case `^`, a regex meaning "the start of a line") and runs the following `ex` editing command on each such line.  Since every line has a start of line, every line matches `^`, so the effect is to run the following command on every line, separately.

Then `.` is an address meaning "the current line (of the buffer)."  Since it's given after the `g` command, it refers to each line of the buffer in turn.

`!` is used to run a shell command.  When it's prefixed by an address (in this case `.`), the given line range (or single line) is fed to the given shell command on *standard input* and the result (standard output) of the command is put in place of that line of the buffer.

In other words, `.!shell-command-here` in `ex` means to filter the current line of the buffer through some external command.

So we've covered how this command setup filters each line of the buffer (individually) through an `awk` command; now let's analyze that `awk` command:

```
awk -v ORS=" " -v RS=" " "/^(def|345)$/"
```

You can define variables for `awk` by using the `-v` flag.  So the first few arguments set the `ORS` and `RS` variables to a single space character.

`RS` in `awk` is the "record separator"; by default its value is a newline.  Whatever character it is set to is what `awk` uses to separate records (usually lines) as they are read in.

Similarly, `ORS`, the "output record separator", controls what `awk` uses to separate the records (usually lines) as they are printed out.

By setting each to a space character, we can operate easily on each word of the line as a single record.

The next portion is the actual `awk` command.  (`awk` is its own scripting language.)  `awk` command blocks consist of conditions and actions; either one can be omitted.  Here, the condition is `/.../` which is a regex match, i.e. this condition applies to all records (words, in this case) which match the given regex.  The regex parts are `^` (start of string), `$` (end of string), and two possible patterns grouped in parentheses, separated with a `|` (pipe) to indicate that either of those patterns is acceptable.

Since there is no action after the condition (an action would be in curly braces for `awk`), awk's default action of "print" is applied to the records matching that condition.  (Remember, this means `awk` will print each matching record (word) of the line, and then `ex` will read that output and put it in place of the line(s) of the buffer that `ex` fed to `awk` in the first place.)

This solution does make the simplifying assumption that all patterns will be matched against complete words, i.e. you will not want to match any patterns that *include* whitespace.  This matches the example input you gave in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk` and only keep the fields you want:

```
echo -e "abc def bac 123\nabc def def bac 123\nabc def def def bac 123 123" \
  | awk -v var1="def" -v var2="123" '{
  i=0
  for (j=1; j<=NF; j++){
    if ($j==var1 || $j==var2){ $++i=$j }
    if (i!=j){ $j="" }
  }
  print
}'
```

This loops through the fields in the for-loop and reassigns `def` or `123` to the next field `$++i=$j` (starting at index 0, so the first field is 1, the next is 2...) and resets current field `$j` to an empty string (`$j=""`) if index `i` is not the loop index `j`.

Output:

```
def 123
def def 123
def def def 123 123
```